# Disable boot-time messages

Tags: boot, pi-4, cmdline.txt, pi4-eeprom

I'm on **Rpi-4** and the OS is **DietPi**.
I have modified /boot/cmdline.txt using the following parameters to disable all and every boot-time logs:

```
console=tty3 root=PARTUUID=907af7d0-02 rootfstype=ext4
elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait net.ifnames=0
logo.nologo consoleblank=0 loglevel=1 quiet vt.global_cursor_default=0 fastboot
```

It has worked and most of the logs are vanished but the following logs are still visible:

[image]

---

### Solution

This is bootloader's log obviously. You can edit its config file using:
`sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit`
and add `DISABLE_HDMI=1` to disable the HDMI boot diagnostics display.
[Rpi official link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md)

Comment: Looks like you are using NOOBS.

Comment: @Milliways Oh I should have mentioned that. It is DietPi in fact.

Comment: those are boot messages, not boot logs  ... logs are stored in a file